# Почему не работают http прокси (библиотека requests python)?

Tags: python, requests, proxy, aiohttp

Изучаю использование прокси в разных библиотеках разным способом. Написал небольшой код:

```
proxies = {
    'http' : 'http://user:pass@11.22.33.44:55',
}

async def get_location(url):

    connector = ProxyConnector.from_url('http://user:pass@11.22.33.44:55')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            print(f'ПРОВЕРКА ПРОКСИ В AIOHTTP:\nIP: {text}\n')


    response = requests.get(url=url, proxies=proxies)
    print(f'ПРОВЕРКА ПРОКСИ В REQUESTS:\nIP: {response.text}\n')

    session = requests.session()
    response = session.request('get', url, proxies=proxies)
    print(f'ПРОВЕРКА ПРОКСИ В REQUESTS-session:\nIP: {response.text}\n')



async def main():
    await get_location('https://icanhazip.com')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

В итоге выдает:

```
ПРОВЕРКА ПРОКСИ В AIOHTTP:
IP: 11.22.33.44

ПРОВЕРКА ПРОКСИ В REQUESTS:
IP: реальный IP

ПРОВЕРКА ПРОКСИ В REQUESTS-session:
IP: реальный IP
```

При замене url-proxy с http на https:

```
proxies = {
    'https' : 'https://user:pass@11.22.33.44:55',
}
connector = ProxyConnector.from_url('https://user:pass@11.22.33.44:55')
```

библиотека Aiohttp исполняет запрос нормально и в ответе отображает IP proxy, но при использовании библиотеки request возникает ошибка. Что я делаю не так? Как мне заставить работать прокси нормально в обоих библиотеках. купленные прокси типа http